# Cómo ajustar el orden de los días de la semana

Tags: sql, sql-server, ordenamiento

Necesito ordenar estos datos para mostrarlo en un `DataGridView` en C#.

En `SQL Server` tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
Día  Descripción
----------------
1   Domingo
2   Lunes
3   Martes
4   Miércoles
5   Jueves
6   Viernes
7   Sábado
```

Pero en la consulta no puedo ordernar el dia con `asc` o `desc`, porque no estará ordenado correctamente:

```
select * from dias_semana order by dia asc
select * from dias_semana order by dia desc
```

**¿Cómo puedo modificar la consulta para mostrarlo ordenado de esta manera?**

```
Día  Descripción
----------------
2   Lunes
3   Martes
4   Miércoles
5   Jueves
6   Viernes
7   Sábado
1   Domingo
```

**Nota:** La tabla contiene mucho más datos, pero el campo `dia` es el único por el cual puedo establecer un orden en la sentencia `select`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar un pequeño truco con el [operador de módulo (`%`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql):

```
select *
  from dias_semanas
 order by (dia + 5) % 7
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/LESEG58565)</kbd>

Comment: Funciona Perfectamente bien, ¿Cómo funciona esto: **(dia + 5) % 7** ?, está muy interesante y un código limpio.

Comment: Me imagino que la parte que tal vez no sea inmediatamente obvia es el uso de `%`, que es el operador de módulo en SQL Server. Su funcionamiento se explica [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql). Pero, en realidad no hay nada mágico, es solo un poco de matemática.

Comment: Si ya vi que editaste la pregunta y pusiste la referencia, no tenia conocimiento de que se podía usar el operador  `%` en una clausula `order by` , cada día se aprende algo nuevo, muchas gracias por compartir.

Comment: Haré el ejemplo con el Lunes, Martes y Domingo que, respectivamente según tus datos, son 2, 3 y 1. Si le sumamos un 5 a estos tres datos, nos daría 7, 8 y 6. Al aplicarle el módulo 7 a estos resultados nos arrojará 0 1 y 6. ¿Por qué? Porque el módulo encuentra el residuo resultante solo si el número es mayor que 7. Solo es un truquito matemático. Así quedarían ordenados los días del 0 al 6.

Comment: @sstan necesito aplicar esta misma lógica a C#, pero en otro contexto esta vez sin cargar los datos desde la base de datos, **¿Formulo una nueva pregunta?** para explicar el caso, es muy similar e igual con los días de la semana

Comment: Puedes formular una nueva pregunta si realmente te trancas en tu código C#, pero en realidad deberías poder resolver el problema usando la misma lógica del `ORDER BY` de la consulta. De hecho, el operador módulo en C# se usa de la misma forma y con el mismo símbolo.